# Why new images are not available?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, asp.net-core-3.1

I am developing a system that uses images. In `wwwroot` I created some folders and put the default image there. I also implemented its registration when starting the project. I bind it to each user when creating an account. This image is displayed normally on the site. But when I try to upload a new image, the browser says that it is not available (404). Although it is created in the same directory as the default image. The database record is successfully created and the new image is correctly associated with the user profile. When inspecting the page and checking the url of the image, I see that it is generated correctly. The name and extension are correct. I take the same url, change the name of the inaccessible file to default, and the browser loads the default image. I tried to upload small pictures with a name with one letter (I suspected that the problem was in the characters in the file name). Restarted the server. Nothing helped.

`Startup.cs`

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IConfiguration config)
    {
        //...
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });

        CreateDefaultImages(serviceProvider);
    }

    private void CreateDefaultImages(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var dbContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var userSettings = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<UserSettings>>();
        var defaultProfilePicture = userSettings.Value.DefaultProfilePicture;
        var img = dbContext.Images.Where(i => i.Filename == defaultProfilePicture).FirstOrDefault();
        
        if(img == null)
        {
            var defaultImage = new Image { Filename = defaultProfilePicture };
            dbContext.Images.Add(defaultImage);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Creating a file on the filesystem

```
public class ImagesManager
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;
    private readonly string _imagesStorage;

    public ImagesManager(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        _environment = environment;
        _imagesStorage = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "Resources", "Images");
    }

    public async Task<Image> CreateAsync(IFormFile file)
    {
        Image createdImage = null;

        try
        {
            string fileName = GenerateUniqueFileName(file.FileName);
            string filePath = Path.Combine(_imagesStorage, fileName);

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }

            createdImage = new Image
            {
                Filename = fileName
            };
        }
        catch { }

        return createdImage;
    }

    // other methods ...
}
```

In short, if miss the controller, creating a view model, and using that model on the page, it all comes down to this code

```
string pathToProfilePicture = $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host.Value}/Resources/Images/{Model.PathToProfilePicture}";
<img src="@pathToProfilePicture">
```

Comment: I think you have a credential issue and do not have permission to read the file.

Comment: @jdweng I changed `FileStream` to `new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read)`, but everything remains the same.

Comment: Can you get the sub-status code of 404? and I found that you mentioned upload small pictures with a name with one letter in your question, do you mean you tried smaller pictures? Because the uploaded file is too large, it will also cause a 404 error.

Comment: What you did has nothing to do with fixing a credential issue.

Comment: @samwu yes, I tried smaller pictures.

Comment: Can you post the details of your error page? I need more information to find the problem.

Comment: @samwu unfortunately, when trying to solve this problem, a new one appeared. I can't even create a file in the file system anymore. The code `await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);` no longer works and I have no idea why. Although I returned the code to its original state. Method `File.Create` working, but I can't write in this file, despite the fact that the `file.OpenReadStream()` is not empty and I can get an array of bytes from it.

Comment: @samwu But when I execute `WriteAllBytes` to the created file, it remains empty and no exceptions are thrown. I have not changed the security settings of the directory. So now I have to solve this problem to answer your question :(

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints to debug your code? Is fileStream null? And I did not find `file.OpenReadStream()` and `WriteAllBytes` in your code.

Comment: @samwu yes, I'm  tried. FileStream is not null. Changing the code and trying to create a file in different ways, I received an array of tens of thousands of bytes from this stream. But when tried either directly with the stream both in the code in the question or through the byte array and method `WriteAllBytes`. As a result, nothing was created either. Or an empty file was created to which nothing was written.

Comment: Can you show me the test code for `WriteAllBytes`?